# Trying to stream to youtube: "default: No such process"

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, streaming, youtube

I'm trying to set up a YouTube stream using ffmpeg, but get this error "default: No such process".
I run this command:
`ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1824x984 -framerate 15 -i :0.0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x800 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 -threads 0 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key"`

And get this response:

```
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --arch=armhf --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[x11grab @ 0x2211710] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1569634587.235443, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1824x984, 15 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
default: No such process
```

I gathered from research that maybe something pointing to the x11grab wasn't accurate, but I'm not sure. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one of the dependencies that `ffmpeg` needs to perform the encoding. Probably `pulseaudio`. On Ubuntu/Debian, try

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the help.